# TOPOLOGY Proving that that the set is a subbasis

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification

Can you check my solution for this question? Thanks

[Click Here For Question And Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGA4s.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe  a little sloppy, but  looks like you proved the union of elements of  $\mathcal JY $is $Y $to me (De Morgan's law i guess).  Except one thing :  shouldn't you say something about  $\mathcal JY $ *generating* $T' $, the (induced) topology on $Y $?  (Though I guess this is trivial. ..)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's right, however you could have shown simply that $Y=X\cap Y=(\bigcup_i B_i)\cap Y=\bigcup_i (B_i\cap Y) =\bigcup_i B'_i$